# Dax formula to extract the first 3 words from a cell?

Tags: powerbi

For example, I have a column titled "root cause" with a sentence describing the cause.

Is it possible to extract the first 3 words?

(or maybe a better than to analysis sentences) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an M Language transformation.

[image]
here an example:

> let
> Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("LcxBCsMwDATAryw+9xPJC3rozfigxKIyRBbYMqG/j0kDu7CwMDGGj5SOGULn6lx3DukVw1LNhRusMs7iArU2l7Xc738txwGhDrfxFQdtNvxPPMKb2mTzUP0hk2KbFdKQ0gU=",
> BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type
> nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Sentence
> = _t]),
> #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Sentence", type text}}),
> #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each Text.Combine(List.FirstN(Text.Split([Sentence]," "), 3), " " )) in
> #"Added Custom"